# How To Handle Python Flask Redirect

Tags: python, flask

I want to know what the best way is to serve up a redirect in Flask. I have a delete button which looks like this:

```
<a href="/elastic_ips/{{region}}/delete/{{eli['public_ip']}}"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-mini" type="button">Delete</button></a>
```

Which calls this app.route:

```
@app.route('/elastic_ips/<region>/delete/<ip>')
def delete_elastic_ip(region=None,ip=None):
        creds = config.get_ec2_conf()
        conn = connect_to_region(region, aws_access_key_id=creds['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'], aws_secret_access_key=creds['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'])
        ip = ip.encode('ascii')
        elis = conn.get_all_addresses(addresses=ip)

        for eli in elis:
                result = []
                r = eli.release()
                result.append(r)
        return Response(json.dumps(result), mimetype='application/json')
```

I rather not return the result as json. I'm not sure what the "proper" way to return to the page with the delete button. Either I can put in an HTML page that just does a redirect to the refer, or is there a built in way in Flask to have return be an app.route?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well if you want to return the url of the `delete_elastic_ip`, it is easy to do with `url_for`  function ([more about this function](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.url_for))

Don't know if this endpoint is in some blueprint, but if not, this is simple as that:

```
from flask import url_for, redirect
.... your code ...
return url_for('delete_elastic_ip', region=None, ip=None)
```

You can replace Nones also with the values you need of course :) And this will return you the url to the endpoint. Btw this is also a way to go with the urls in templates. Do not hardcode them, use url_for function in jinja templates to generate urls to the views for you. The function is available as a standart global variable in templates ([more](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/templating/))

Also if you want just to redirect directly to some other endpoint and do not return anything, there is a function `redirect` in flask. Use it combined with url_for and you are good to go ;)

```
from flask import url_for, redirect
... your code...
return redirect(url_for('delete_elastic_ip', region=None, ip=None))
```

It will refresh the page, so not the best way for ajax redirect though if you want that. For ajax, just return json with the url_for result and do the stuff with it.

Comment: Thanks, actually I wanted to go back to the page which calls the delete_elastic_ip function, but you explained it perfectly!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another method using render_template
app.py code

```
from flask import Flask, request,render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():

    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/v_timestamp')
def v_timestamp():

    return render_template('v_timestamp.html')
```

then can redirect to v_timestamp page. If you want this to be done via a button click event. Inside template folder, in your v_timestamp.html have this bit of code

```
<p align="center"><a href=v_timestamp ><button class=grey style="height:75px;width:150px">v timestamp</button></a></p>
```

define button element and an a href inside the same paragraph element, in my case a href v_timestamp means v_timetsamp.html write the respective   .html page you want to redirect towards.

**File structure**
-app.py 
-templates

- index.html
- v_timestamp.html